# Regex - remove the first letters until the first vowel

Tags: regex

I have a list of words and I would like to remove the first letters until the first vowel.

I'm not great with regexes but I know it would be the best solution. I'm using javascript (if that helps).

Below is what I would like to be returned (input > output).

```
Art > Art
Cheat > eat
Cart > art
Jog > og
Fun > un
eat > eat
Beat > eat
meat > eat
Run > un
Smart > art
cat > at
blog > og
```

Comment: Perhaps something like this would work: `^[^aeiou]+` - replace with empty string.

Comment: What is the expected result for `CTRL`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex pattern: `^[^aeiou]+` with the `i` (case-insentive) flag set

**Explanation:**

- `^` - anchor representing the start of the string
- `[^aeiou]+` - any repeating characters that are not vowels (A, E,I, O, U)

Replace any matches of that pattern with a blank string (`''`)

**Javascript**

```
const words = ['Art', 'Cheat', 'Cart', 'Jog', 'Fun', 'eat', 'Beat', 'meat', 'Run', 'Smart', 'cat', 'blog'];
const regex = /^[^aeiou]+(?=[aeiou])/gi; // NOTICE THE i FLAG HERE

for(i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
  console.log(words[i] + ' > ' + words[i].replace(regex, ''));
```

Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/sezuvewumu/edit?js,console) of the example code above

Comment: should be `^[^aeiou]*`(star instead of plus)

Comment: @Posix why? There's no reason to match an empty string at the start of the input and replace it with the empty string.

Comment: @Ewan The loop here is only to demonstrate the replace on each of your words. You can use `str.replace(regex, '')` on a single word in variable named `str` without a loop.

Comment: yeah sorry, didn't read it properly. It works perfect. Thanks!